# Windows 7 bit locker not responding

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I locked my 300 gb hard drive partition with windows bit locker,
one day was trying to open the drive but during the process power failure occurred.
I restarted the pc but when I tried to unlock the drive system becomes unresponsive, I wait for long time but nothing happened. I don,t have the recovery key or recovery password. What can do..

Comment: "BitLocker is designed to make the encrypted drive unrecoverable without the required authentication. When in recovery mode, the user needs the recovery password or recovery key to unlock the encrypted drive." from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh831507.aspx#BKMK_KeyManagement

Comment: I have the password that i used last time to open the drive...but the whole problem is caused by the power failure during the decryption process

Comment: A computer guy took 1000 Rupees from me and gave all of my data to me.